# Une formulation concise pour « trouver une borne de la valeur absolue de (quelque chose) »

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques

Le néerlandais utilise un mot particulier pour « trouver une borne de la valeur absolue de (quelque chose) ».

Évidemment, pour tout nombre fini, il existe une borne qui est plus grande que la valeur absolue de ce nombre. Il s’agit ici de trouver une borne qui ne dépend que de certaines inconnues.

C’est un mot usité et très adroit si on essaie de fournir une preuve analytique, il se dit littéralement « déestimer » ou peut-être plutôt « abestimer ».
Je n’ai jamais trouvé de mot français que je puisse utiliser en guise de traduction.
J’espère que vous pourrez me donner un tel mot.

Il est pensable que ce mot ne puisse pas être traduit. Dans ce cas, je voudrais connaitre des tournures proches ou d'autres astuces pour exprimer « qu’on cherche un majorant de la valeur absolue ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*on fait un majorant*" ça se dit *Majorer*.

Donc, je dirais "Majorer en valeur absolue".

Comment: Pourquoi pas « majorer **la** valeur absolue » ?

Comment: On peut lire "Majorer cette fonction en valeur absolue" ou "Majorer la valeur absolue de cette fonction".

Comment: @Jhyn: Techniquement une fonction n'a pas de valeur absolue. Elle peut avoir une norme, mais c'est différent, il ne s'agit plus d'une majoration point par point. *Majorer en valeur absolue* est le seul raccourci dans ce cas.